# Is it possible to render AO with the OpenGL render?

Tags: rendering, shaders, opengl

Is it possible to render AO with the openGL render?

I know there is a [technique called SSAO which is used in some video games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_space_ambient_occlusion), so it should be possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That would be really cool. Why can't Blender look like Crysis?

Comment: This can be done in the game engine in realtime.

Comment: @iKlsR How? And can it be used for rendering an animation?

Comment: http://devlog-martinsh.blogspot.com/2011/10/nicer-ssao.html

Comment: @iKlsR That shader looks like [this](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=65133) for some reason :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a hack to fake AO in the viewport using negative lamps.

[image]

The way this works is with a negative point lamp parented at the center of each cube, and an array of negative point lamps below the floor plane:

[image]

For the floor it would be more ideal to use an area lamp, however these are only supported in the [BGE candy branch](http://graphicall.org/885).

The world is set to *Paper* with a pure white *Horizon Color*. The *Ambient color* is also set to white.

*GLSL* shading and *Only Render* are also enabled.

[**Blendfile**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26239)